# application_id for promoted_object for AdSet of Facebook Marketing API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Question about `application_id` for [`promoted_object`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adset/v2.3#promoted_object) of [Facebook Marketing API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis).

I'm trying to create Ads for mobile applications published to Apple App Store or Google Play Market. These are applications of my clients, they are not mine and I don't have access to them.

I have successfully created [`AdCampaign`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adcampaign/v2.3#create) object with `objective=MOBILE_APP_INSTALLS`.

But I can't create [`AdSet`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adset/v2.3#create) object for this campaign.

`AdSet` requires [`promoted_object`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adset/v2.3#promoted_object) with `application_id` and `object_store_url` fields provided. While I can provide `object_store_url` (it's just a link to application [app store page](https://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/xiao-ou-wo-de3d-meng-ou/id867964769?mt=8)) but I can't provide `application_id` for this app because this application is not mine.

At the same time **business.facebook.com** web interface does not require `application_id`. It requires `application_url` only. Screenshots: http://take.ms/jFQyY http://take.ms/CCBGM http://take.ms/pmNap

How can I retrieve `application_id` using application appstore url?
Or maybe it is possible not to specify `application_id` field for `promoted_object` of `AdCampaign` with `objective=MOBILE_APP_INSTALLS` at all?

Comment: Did you figure out an alternative?

Comment: @PratikBothra, in some measure.
1) The wrong way. You can create application manually in your Facebook Developer account. To do that you don't have to be an owner of iOS/Android native application. But you can't create applications via Facebook API. You have to create it manually in Facebook web interface. :facepalm:

Comment: @PratikBothra, 2) The right way. I'm only planning to try it. You have to ask original application owner to grant you access to his/her Facebook applications (via oauth2). Having granted access you will be able to find required application via Facebook Graph API.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Marketing API documentation for "[Creating Ad Sets with Promoted Object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adset/v2.3#promoted_object)", it says "You cannot specify an object_store_url on its own without an application_id, this is something only available via our native interfaces.".

To retrieve the application_id, you may try the [Connection Objects API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/connectionobjects/v2.3) to get the list of connected Applications to your Ad User account. Your clients need to grant you the advertiser role to their Facebook Application first before you can start listing the applications via Connection Objects API.

Connection Objects API is able to return the object_store_urls, which means you don't need to provide the app store URL manually.